# how to convert array into variables in php

Tags: php

I want to create a function that takes the name of a table and an array with the column name and value to use it to generate an INSERT in MySQL

Check my code.

Unfortunately this technique does not work as it always generates a comma after each value and this generates an error when entering data. Anyone know a better way to create this function?

```
<?php
$arrayDados = array('nome' => 'Renato', 'idade' => 24, 'peso' => 36, 'mae' => 'neide');
$colunas = "";
$valores = "";
$tabela = 'cadastro';

    foreach ($arrayDados as $key => $value) {
        $colunas .=  $key . ', ';
        $valores .= $value.', ';
    }
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela ($colunas) VALUES ($valores)";

echo $sql;`
```

Comment: use `implode(',', array_keys($arrayDados))` for columns and `implode("','", array_values($arrayDados))` for values

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `implode()`:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
implode(',', $yourArray);
```

Really though, use prepared queries instead of stuff like this where possible, to avoid problems with unescaped data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela (".implode(",",array_keys($arrayDados)).") VALUES (".implode(",",array_values($arrayDados)).")";
```

Docs: [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array-keys) - [`array_values`](http://php.net/array-values) - [`implode`](http://php.net/implode)